# Disable refresh button click for javascript timer

Tags: javascript, html, web, timer

I'm working on the timer module for a quiz project. I have created a timer program it works as expected. But when I click the refresh button the timer restarts. I want the timer to not be affected by the refresh button click. How to achieve this.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">


var timer = 3600;
var min=0;
var sec = 0;

function starttimer()
{

min=parseInt(timer/60);
sec=parseInt(timer%60);

if(timer<1)

{

window.location="over.html";

}

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML="<b> Time Left: </b>" 
+min.toString()+":"+sec.toString();
timer--;
setTimeout(function(){
starttimer();

},1000);

}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="starttimer();">

<h1> Test Page  </h1>
<div>
<center><b>[<span id="time"></span></b>]</center>
</div>
```

Comment: You would be better off using the time as a start reference and computing the elapsed time/time left based on that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `localStorage` to store the timer position and retrieve the same from `localStorage`.

***Storing*** :

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

***Retrieving***

```
localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Comment: Note that just saving its value will essentially be pausing the timer when the code isn't running. Recording a time and then computing the timer based on that will allow for more accurate timing and won't be affected by the page being closed.

Comment: I'm a newbie in javascript. I dont know where to add the code.

Comment: @Solomon_Arvind Read the [web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) documentation. Experiment with it and figure it out. If you run into problems search Google and here, and if you can't find anything you can post a new question.